# username saving as null in django custom model

Tags: django, django-models

when i am sending post request to register new user from postman, username saves as blank/dash .
why username saving as blank i dont get it.
but when i add from django admin it saves correctly.

here is postman image
[postman post request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45rlt.png)

and here is the result

[django result after sending post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT7M4.png)

Custom Account Manager

```
class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_admin', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:            
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(email, username, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an username'))
        if " " in username:
            raise ValueError(_('Username should not contain space'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Custom User Model

```
class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    objects = CustomAccountManager()
    # more
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'NewUser'

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

model serializer

```
class RegisterNewUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'username')
        extra_kwargs={'password':{'write_only':True}}
    def validate(self, data):
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_data'):
            unknown_keys = set(self.initial_data.keys()) - set(self.fields.keys())
            if unknown_keys:
                raise ValidationError("Got unknown fields: {}".format(unknown_keys))
        return data
    def validate_username(self, value):
        if " " in value:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Username should not contain space")
  
    def save(self):
        newuser = NewUser(email = self.validated_data['email'],
        username = self.validated_data['username']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']

        newuser.set_password(password)
        newuser.save()
        return newuser
```

post request

```
class RegistrationView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [ AllowAny ]
    def post(self, request):
        reg_serializer = RegisterNewUserSerializer(data = request.data)
        print(request.data)
        print(reg_serializer)
        if reg_serializer.is_valid():
            print('lololololololololololo')
            reg_serializer.save()
            return Response(data=request.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(reg_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You validator should return the data, so:

```
def validate_username(self, value):
    if " " in value:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Username should not contain space")
    #        ↓ return the value
    return value
```

In Python a function call *always* returns something (unless an exception is raised). If no explicit `return` statement is triggered, `None` is returned.